# Can this function: $\int_0^t({B_s}^2+s)^2$ $ds$ be simplified any further using Ito's Lemma or other methods?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I want to calculate the value of this function: $\int_0^t({B_s}^2+s)^2$ $ds$, however I think this may be as simple as it gets. I have no way of telling for certain- could someone more knowledgeable possibly guide me as to how I might simplify it?

Comment: By value what do you mean...? Expected value?